# Cannot pass whitespace separated value to Query

Tags: mysql

My project with PHP and MySql stuck here ,

```
$searchfriend = "Jason";

$status = query("SELECT status FROM users.profile WHERE name = ?" , $searchfriend );
```

The above statement works quite well.

When I replace,

```
$searchfriend = "Jason R"
```

It's not working. What is the solution ?
I have created my own query function with PDO.

```
function query()
{

    $sql = func_get_arg(0);
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working" - do you get some error? Empty results?

Comment: do you have record with the value "Jason R" in the name field?

Comment: yes, I have a record with Jason R in name field.
Initially, I tried,
`$status = query("SELECT status FROM users.profile WHERE name = ?" , $_POST["name"] );`

It shows error.So, Again, I tried,
`$searchfriend = $_POST["name"] ;
$status = query("SELECT status FROM users.profile WHERE name = ?" , $searchfriend );`

Again, error. Final try is,
`$searchfriend = "Jason R";
$status = query("SELECT status FROM users.profile WHERE name = ?" , $searchfriend );`

This even is not working?

Comment: Let's verify some things; please provide `echo $sql;` and `print_r($parameters);`